# Does, S = k ln W == W = e^s/k?

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms, entropy

"Boltzmann's equation relates the entropy S of an ideal gas to the number W of microstates corresponding to a given macrostate, via the equation

S = k ln W

where k is the so-called Boltzmann constant. Rearrange this formula to make W the subject"

S = k ln W
S/k = ln W
W = e^S/k

Is this correct? Thanks!

p.s how do i get the exponent to format without the ^ ? And can i write a log, eg. log 5, with the base 5 (or whatever number, e, etc) formatted correctly? I'm new around here..

Comment: `$W=e^{S/k}$` `$\log_5(x)$` etc. Where is your mathematical question?

Comment: Did you go through the tour of the session.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Check this out...

Comment: "Rearrange this formula to make W the subject"  I'm asking if the formula has be rearranged correctly to make W the subject.

Comment: On the Help page, click on "How do I format mathematics here"? ....and on subsequent links.... Your Answer is correct, provided that $ k \ne 0.$ In physics, zero entropy would require a universe with at most 1 particle or a universe of age 0.

Comment: $W=e^\frac{S}{k}$

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$$W=e^\frac{S}{k}$$

`$W=e^\frac{S}{k}$`

Comment: I am sorry Daniel. I am too new to the forum. Have hardly become active. I will take care next time. Thanks for your valuable suggestion / warning.

Comment: I am deleting this Answer as this has been marked no worth as an answer. Thank You Daniel. I have added the answer in the comment above.

Comment: I don't have the permission to delete this answer....? What to do.